# Salesforce api client

Tags: .net, rest, api, salesforce

I'm starting new integration app. that will need to read and write data to and from Salesforce Org using .net C#

In the past I have used two different technologies:  Salesforce.Force.ForceClient  and 
Devart.Data.Salesforce

Force client is native (my understanding) to Saleforce.
Devart on the other hand is nice because it simplifies SF down to regular DB access.

What's the better technology to use for the Access to Salesforce org in the fall of 2019?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good question, very subjective. Pick whatever's easiest, best for the project. Realtime sync or nightly jobs? Push, pull? Error handling? Ease of reacting to change (what if new field is added in SF?)

Nothing is "native". You don't have direct access to underlying database, all .NET libraries will use SOAP or REST API, question is how well they will hide it, how easy it'll be for you to use them. If you want to treat SF as "yet another generic ODBC database" check out (paid!) https://forceamp.com/. If you use Azure services, there's decent plugin for Data Factory (but that's more for batch loads, not realtime sync)

https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET seems to be still actively maintained. Or go with SOAP API, download a WSDL file, consume it (let VisualStudio generate classes out of it for you) and operate on them as if they're normal objects, not caring that behind the scenes they run callouts.

This might help: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_developer_environment_dotnet_tipsheet.meta/salesforce_developer_environment_dotnet_tipsheet/salesforce_developer_environment_dotnet_roadmap.htm